# Agora live streaming Quality configuration

Tags: live-streaming, agora.io

I've been working on a flutter based project where the scope is to build live streaming functionality. I have used the flutter agora-rtc plugin for this with

video Dimensions: 1080:1920 in the configuration.

It works decent on high speed internet. But when the speed drops the video starts to stutter and lag a lot.

Can you please suggest a dimension and video configuration which will work on 1mbps speed with a decent quality

Answer (score 0):

Setting video configuration based on the internet speed that you mentioned is not the only factor over here. You need to consider the number of simultaneous streams that will be played. Generally, a live stream requires higher bandwidth than a video regular call. You can refer this guide which can help you select the configuration based on your internet speed -https://docs.agora.io/en/All/faq/video_profile